# Scrapy removes query strings in response

Tags: python-2.7, web-scraping, scrapy

In `scrapy shell` when I tried using `fetch` on a Google' search result page:

`$ scrapy shell "http://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=%22german+beer+near%22&start=0"`

I got a response without the query string after '#'

`[s]   request    <GET http://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=jeffrey+m+liebmann>
[s]   response   <200 http://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl>`

Is this issue belongs to scrapy or Google? Tried pasting the whole URL + query string and Google led me to the results just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google switched from http to https awhile ago, so you just need to simply remove `gws_rd=ssl` from your request url. Try this:

```
scrapy shell "https://www.google.fr/search?q=%22german+beer+near%22&start=0"
```

and the respose will be:

```
[s]   request    <GET https://www.google.fr/search?q=%22german+beer+near%22&start=0>
[s]   response   <200 https://www.google.fr/search?q=%22german+beer+near%22&start=0>
```